# MQTT events from loop() in Tkinter Gui are not catched

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, mqtt

I'am building a small Tkinter App with MQTT. In spite of the dominant Tkinter mainloop() I try to poll the MQTT events with the Tkinter after() and the MQTT loop() function. But the event 'connecthandler' are not processed. I can see the connection on my mqtt server.

Any tips would be appreciated

Here is the simplified version:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()
        self.initMQTT()
        
    def initMQTT(self):
        self.mqc=mqtt.Client()
        self.mqc.on_connect=self.connecthandler
        self.mqc.on_disconnect=self.disconnecthandler
        self.mqc.connect('localhost',1883,60)
        self.setMQTTPoll()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("MQTT")
        self.parent.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (100, 100, 100, 100))
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="top")

        self.parent.bind('<Button-3>', self.clickRight)
        self.parent.bind('q', self.leave)
        
    def leave(self, event="none"):
        self.quit()
    
    def clickRight(self, event="none"):
        print("rightClick")
    
    def connecthandler(self, obj, flags, rc):
        print("Connected to MQTT broker with rc=%d" % (rc))

    def disconnecthandler(self,obj, rc):
        print("Disconnected from MQTT broker with rc=%d" % (rc))
            
    def setMQTTPoll(self):
        self.after(300, self.mqttLoop)

    def mqttLoop(self):
        self.mqc.loop()
        self.setMQTTPoll()
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `setMQTTPoll` and `mqttLoop` are running?

Comment: Maybe the `connecthandler(self, obj, flags, rc)` needs another function signature, with other parameters? This documentation looks quite different, from what you have: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#client

Comment: thx @swiesend. your right. one parameter is missing. now it is working with `  def connecthandler(self, client , obj, flags, rc):`